# Is there a way to load files into stack but into an already opened file in Photoshop CC?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

I know that I can Scripts > Load files into stack. This will create a NEW document where each external image is it's own layer. I'm wondering if there's a way to do that but load that stack into an existing document that is already opened.

Comment: Can you include the existing document into the group stacked by the script?

Comment: I'm not writing a script, the option is actually called Load Files into Stack under a label Scripts.

Comment: I'm suggesting that you close the PSD and add it to the files that you load into the stack.

Comment: Not sure if that would work, but worth a try.

Comment: So it does work to a degree; it loads the top layer of the PSD, but not anything else. So if your PSD file has 5 layers and you stak 2 images plus that PSD, you'll get a total of only three layers. The other issue with this solution is that I have think way in advance if I'll ever work with this PSD and other files in one stack. I work with a ton of file so to think that far ahead is fruitless for me. I'm looking for a way to import stacked images into an open PSD. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the *Scripts -> Load files into stack* option. The files will be opened in a new document.
2. Select all files in the new document and then select Layer -> Duplicate layer...
3. Provide the correct destination (old document)

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!